# Android SharedPreferences getString - Required String , Found java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, string

I am learning how to develop apps for Android in java. I have made my own `ArrayAdapter`. In its `getView` method I want to change the string used by a `TextView`. I want to get this string from the `SharedPreferences`.

*Code is at the bottom of the post.*

AndroidStudio is telling me there is an error in this line:

```
String description = prefs.getString(title + "description", "missing description");
```

`Incompatible types. Required: String, Found: java.lang.String`

Far as I know these things are the same thing. But I cannot run my program because of this error. How do I get rid of it?

---

```
public class NiceAdapter<String> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private final SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private ArrayList<String> items;

    public NiceAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> passedItems) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, passedItems);

        items = passedItems;
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("NiceListPrefs", ListActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);

        TextView titleView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView descriptionView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        String title = items.get(position);
        titleView.setText(title.toString());

        String description = prefs.getString(title + "description", "missing description");
        descriptionView.setText(description);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: any chance you defined a class named `String`?

Comment: how did you declare your class ? `public class MyClass<String> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {` ?

Comment: How and where did you declare the SharedPreference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
public class NiceAdapter<String> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
```

with

```
public class NiceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
```

With  `NiceAdapter<String>` you are defining a generic type called String, which is not what `SharedPreferences.getString` expects